# What can I do about in company raises?

Tags: professionalism

I received a .22 cent per hour raise I noticed that a coworker doing the same job as me received at .50 per hour raise and has been there less time than myself what should i do?

Answer (score 5):

You talk to your supervisor and find out what you need to do to get to the compensation level you want. You don't know what other circumstances are around your co-worker's raise, and what he gets should have nothing to do with what you get.

- He might have a stronger background which will make him better at that job
- He might be a better negotiator than you
- He might be better at [paying attention to fine details](http://consumerist.com/2006/12/08/verizon-doesnt-know-difference-between-dollars-and-cents/), which makes him stand out from you (for example, you probably didn't get a raise of 0.0022 dollars per hour, which is what your "0.22 cent per hour" is) or makes him more valuable to the organization

Spending a lot of time being upset about someone else getting different pay than you **without knowing why** will just put you in a bad place. There's nothing that you can do or not do to change that other person's wages. Focus on making yourself the best **you** can be, and prove your value. If you feel that you're not being compensated fairly for the value that **you produce**, talk to the people who make the money decisions - or find somewhere else to work that will pay you what you feel you're worth.

Comment: He might have also had a lower rate than the OP, before the increases. So many factors. (Excellent answer BTW.)

Comment: Good point, @Leigh. One thing I'm now wondering about - how does one "notice" that a co-worker got a raise, without also discovering if there's an actual disparity between their wages.

Comment: If a company doesn't have a policy to openly post various wages, or if the person in question doesn't share what they are and were making...I have absolutely no idea how one would learn this information. The one and only time I had concrete knowledge that I was getting a different wage than someone else doing - literally - the exact same job while sitting right next to me...it was most definitely a case of "I was a better negotiator." And I wouldn't have known a thing if we hadn't been housemates and good friends. (Still are. Good friends, that is, not housemates.)

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your manager. You could say that you are aware that employees don't always get the same level of pay raise, and you would like to know if there is something you could be doing differently, ways you could improve, concerns you may need to address in order to get a bigger raise.

There are all sorts of things that factor into raises besides length of employment and job description. Employees who demonstrate some leadership skills, who pursue professional development or education, who are quick to pitch in when needed, or who are demonstrably smart might be worth more to a company thatn another employee.

Comment: In my case, the employee had a much better advocate (me) than I had (none) when I was in the employee's position. It's as simple as that.